# How do I POST an array to a web api controller from an HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Inside a web api controller I have the following method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ProcessResultDto Process(int[] IDs)
{
}
```

I cannot change that signature or dll or anything.

I have to make an executable that calls that method.

Here's roughly what I have so far:

```
int[] ids = //...
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = // I don't know what goes here.
    var result = cli.PostAsync("/api/Processor/Process", content).Result;
    string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    // Substring(6) because of leading )]}',\n
    var summary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProcessResultDto>(resultContent.Substring(6));
    return summary;
}
```

What do I set content to so that I can pass an array of int's to my web api controller

Comment: Maybe `new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }));` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
int[] ids = new[] {1,2,3,4};
var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
   IDs = ids
});
```

This will create an anonymous object with a property of `IDs` and convert it to json. The json will look like:

```
{
    IDs: [1,2,3,4]
}
```

The web API method will then bind that to your model.

Answer (score 1):

I use [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text)'s JSON serializer/deserializer as they're the current .Net performance champ. From the ServiceStack docs

> Any List, Queue, Stack, Array, Collection, Enumerables including custom enumerable types are stored in exactly the same way as a JavaScript array literal

Therefore

```
int[] ids = [1,2,3,4];
var content = TypeSerializer.SerializeToString(new {IDs=ids});
```